# Customs toString in Java not giving desired output and throwing error

Tags: java, date, boolean, comparable

I am writing a program in Java to accept and validate dates according to the Gregorian Calendar. My public boolean setDate(String aDate) function for an incorrect entry is suppose to change the boolean goodDate variable to false. That variable is suppose tell the toString function, when called, to output "Invalid Entry" but it does not. My public boolean setDate(int d, int m, int y) function works fine though. I've only included the problem parts as its a long piece of code. Thanks

```
 public boolean setDate(int day, int month, int year){
    // If 1 <= day <= 31,  1 <= month <= 12, and 0 <= year <= 9999 & the day match with the month
    // then set object to this date and return true
    // Otherwise,return false (and do nothing)
    boolean correct = isTrueDate(day, month, year);
    if(correct){
      this.day = day;
      this.month = month;
      this.year = year;
      return true;
    }else{
      goodDate = false;
      return false;
    }
    //return false;
}

public boolean setDate(String aDate){
    // If aDate is of the form "dd/mm/yyyy" or "d/mm/yyyy" 
    // Then set the object to this date and return true.
    // Otherwise, return false (and do nothing)
    Date d = new Date(aDate);
    boolean correct = isTrueDate(d.day, d.month, d.year);
    if(correct){
      this.day = d.day;
      this.month = d.month;
      this.year = d.year;
      return true;
    }else{
      goodDate = false;
      return false;
    }
}

public String toString(){
    // outputs a String of the form "dd/mm/yyyy"
    // where dd must be 2 digits (with leading zero if needed)
    //       mm must be 2 digits (with leading zero if needed)
    //     yyyy must be 4 digits (with leading zeros if needed)
    String day1;
    String month1;
    String year1;
    if(day<10){
      day1 = "0" + Integer.toString(this.day);
    } else{
      day1 = Integer.toString(this.day);
    }
    if(month<10){
      month1 = "0" + Integer.toString(this.month);
    } else{
      month1 = Integer.toString(this.month);
    }
    if(year<10){
      year1 = "00" + Integer.toString(this.year);
    } else{
      year1 = Integer.toString(this.year);
    }
    if(goodDate){
    return day1 +"/" +month1 +"/" + year1;
    }else{
      goodDate = true;
      return "Invalid Entry";
    }

  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A MAJOR problem with this code is that your `toString()` function modifies the state of the program (by setting `goodDate` to true).  The problem is that toString could be being called anywhere in your code, even if you don't explicitly call it.  So, I'd be willing to bet that something else is calling it and setting `goodDate` to true.  See if you can find a way to make the `toString()` function not change the state.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to do in the third-party library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3. When instantiating a new [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instance, the class throws an exception if invalid values are passed to the constructor.

Code below makes use of the new [Multi-Catch Exceptions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html) feature in Java 7.

Example source code:

- Invoice class, just some place to put the method to try validity of potential new date-time.
- Other code that instantiates an Invoice then calls the validity method.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

public class Invoice {

    Boolean isDateTimeValid (int year, int month, int day) {
        org.joda.time.DateTimeZone losAngelesTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
        try {
            org.joda.time.DateTime dt = new org.joda.time.DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, losAngelesTimeZone);
            return true; // No exception thrown, so this must be a valid date-time.
        } catch (org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException e) {
            return false; // Oops, invalid values used as input.
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR Encountered an unexpected Exception: " + e.getStackTrace() );
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Code any place to call that validity method.

```java
Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
System.out.println( "Is valid date for 2013, 11, 15: " + invoice.isDateTimeValid(2013, 11, 15) );
System.out.println( "Is valid date for 2013, 99, 15: " + invoice.isDateTimeValid(2013, 99, 15) );
```

When run…

```
Is valid date for 2013, 11, 15: true
Is valid date for 2013, 99, 15: false
```

About Joda-Time and related issues…

```java
// Joda-Time - The popular alternative to Sun/Oracle's notoriously bad date, time, and calendar classes bundled with Java 7 and earlier.
// http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

// Joda-Time will become outmoded by the JSR 310 Date and Time API introduced in Java 8.
// JSR 310 was inspired by Joda-Time but is not directly based on it.
// http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310

// By default, Joda-Time produces strings in the standard ISO 8601 format.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

// About Daylight Saving Time (DST): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

// Time Zone list: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
```